# In python are integers such as 2013 treated as arrays just as strings are such as "dog"?

Tags: python, arrays, string, int

I need to know if integers can be treated as arrays just like strings can for this problem: Problem Description
You might be surprised to know that 2013 is the ﬁrst year since 1987 with distinct digits. The years
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019 each have distinct digits. 2012 does not have distinct digits,
since the digit 2 is repeated.
Given a year, what is the next year with distinct digits?
Input Speciﬁcation
The input consists of one integer Y (0  Y  10000), representing the starting year.

The reason why is because I keep getting an error message that says "int" object is not iterable.

Here is my code. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
def distinct(year):

    elements = []
    for j in range (year, 10000):
        elements.append(max(year))
        year.pop(year.index(max(year)))

        elements.append(min(year))
        year.pop(year.index(min(year)))

        if ((j not in elements) and (j not in year)):
            return j
            break 

def main():
    print (distinct(int(input('Please enter a year'))))

main()
```

Comment: Now, the question is to guess where `"int" object is not iterable.` error is thrown?

Comment: btw strings are not array, if you want to treat like string in the sense making it iterable, you need to convert the int into string and you can use all the methods in string like `for i in string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no. Numbers are numbers. You can however simply get a string representation by passing them as an argument to the str class:

```
year = 2012
str_year = str(year)
for digit in str_year:
    print digit
```

Comment: Or they could just not call `int` on their string in the first place.

Comment: I understood your reply and I proceeded to making a for loop that cycles through each number of the string "2013" for example, but I'm still getting the int object is not iterable. Specifically here is the error I'm getting:

Comment: Please enter a year2013
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yazad\Dropbox\Grade 12\Computer Science\From 1898 to 2013.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Yazad\Dropbox\Grade 12\Computer Science\From 1898 to 2013.py", line 33, in main
    print (distinct(int(input('Please enter a year'))))
  File "C:\Users\Yazad\Dropbox\Grade 12\Computer Science\From 1898 to 2013.py", line 6, in distinct
    elements.append(max(year))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @user1814771 Do you think this is more readable than properly editing your question?

Comment: I suggest you'd spend some time in the Pythoin itneractive prompt, and learn the difference between entering, for example `a= 2013` and `b="2013"` at the prompt, then trying to get the digits `b[0]`, and converting one type to another, as in `c=str(a); c[0]` - you won't get any far if you dont grasp these basics.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate other digits in a year number, you shouldn't cast the input as an `int`. A string is considered as a list of characters, so you can iterate over each digit (and cast them into `int` if you want after):

```
>>> for number in "2012":
...     print number
...
2
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> n = 2014
>>> list(n)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> list(str(n))
['2', '0', '1', '4']
```